# I want to have my nav bar in my header next to my logo

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I've made a website for a school project and want to improve the design a little more. I think the logo makes the header a little bit to big. So I want to move my navbar from under the header to inside the header, to make it look smaller. That's all. I'll post the code and photos underneath.

**This is how it looks now**

[image: original]

**How I want it to be**

[image: required]

```css
/* -----------------------
Layout 
------------------------*/

.container {
  max-width: 70em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
  font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
  color: #fff;
  background: #7eabac;
  padding: 0.5em 0em;
}
.header-heading {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
.nav-bar {
  background: #e9f1f1;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1em 1.25em;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.main,
.zijkant {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.footer {
  color: #fff;
  background: #656565;
  padding: 1em 1.25em;
}
/* -----------------------
Navbar
------------------------*/

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: .7em 1.25em;
  color: #black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.nav a:link {
  color: black;
}
.nav a:visited {
  color: black;
}
.nav a:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.nav a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: #eededb;
}
.nav a:active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #f4ebe9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="etc/css/styles.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function zoom() {
    document.body.style.zoom = "-20%"
  }
</script>

<body onload="zoom()">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="etc/img/logo-wec.png" class="header-heading"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="nieuws.html">Nieuws</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="producten.html">Producten</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="bestellen.html">ROC</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: from a UX point of view, I wouldn't suggest doing that since moving it to the right side makes it hard to locate and access it at a glance.

Comment: And your snippet differs from the images you provided

Answer (score 1):

Put the image container and navbar in the same container:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="etc/img/logo-wec.png" class="header-heading"></img>
    </div>
<div class="nav-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="nieuws.html">Nieuws</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="producten.html">Producten</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="bestellen.html">ROC</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Give the header position relative and the position the navbar using absolute positioning:

```
.header {
  font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
  color: #fff;
  background: #7eabac;
  padding: 0.5em 0em;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-bar{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
height: 50px;//adjust to center vertically
width: 300px;//adjust to your liking
}
```

You have to set a height to nav-bar in order to make sure it is centered vertically